# Finding probability with combination

Tags: probability, combinations

So, the question is: 
 There are 7 students in a class: 2 boys and 5 girls. 
If the teacher picks a group of 3 at random, what is the probability that everyone in the group is a girl?
 Actually, I know how to solve this problem using combination: $\frac{\text{# of ways to choose 3 girls out of  5}}{\text{total number of ways to choose 3 students out of 7}}$ which yields $\frac{2}{7}$. I wanted to solve this problem in a different way but failed and want to know why? So, what I tried to do was to find probability of getting one group of 3 girls, GGG, which is $(\frac{5}{7})^3$. Then multiplied it with the # of ways to choose 3 girls out of 5, which is 10, and  got totally different result, 3.6 .
 So what is wrong with the second approach?
P.S. It is the first time I am asking a question here and therefore i am sorry if there is any problem with the post overall.

Comment: The $\left (\frac 57 \right)^3$ is wrong.  That would be right if you were choosing with replacement, but the context makes it clear that you are not.  Choosing a girl first lowers the probability that the second is also a girl.  To take a more extreme example, if the teacher chose $6$ students, the probability that they are all girls is $0$, not $\left( \frac 57\right)^6$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you've found the answer to your question, you should write an answer to your question and accept your own answer so others will know that it's resolved and can take that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: 5/7 * 4/6 * 3/5 which makes 2/7. (5/7)^3 is wrong because, as lulu pointed out, choosing a girl first lowers the probability that the second is also a girl. Multiplying by 10 is also wrong because there is only one unique collection of a group of 3 girls, GGG.